# Implementing a "fill in" field

Tags: android, forms

I am currently developing an educational application for high school students to take exams and quizzes. There are several types of "questions" per exams, such as the one that use checkboxes or radio buttons. But there is one type of question I don't know how to implement it at logic or database level. It is the type of  question like "The first Olympic games were celebrated in the city of ***_*__*_*__*_*__*_*_**, in Greece". My app is being made in Android, but I will appreciate any "high-level" implementation idea. Thanks

Comment: you could use a clickable span that opens an input popup

Comment: This question wouldn't have radio buttons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an `EditText`. Documentation is located here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/EditText.html.

You would add this to your xml layout file:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent">
</EditText>
```

You can then have the user press a button when they completed the questions, and have this code in the onClick:

```
final EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit);
String Value = edit.getText().toString();
```

Comment: Yes but if the EditText is between two Strings like in the example question above, would it be necessary to have to separate TextViews and the EditText in between them?

Comment: Probably. Or, you could put a space in 1 TextView that is equal to the length of the EditText and a bit more.